# Fiddler behavior during timeout

Tags: ajax, timeout, fiddler

I'm using Fiddler to track down a timeout issue between the browser app and server. What I want to find out is whether the server is sending a response that is ignored by the browser or whether the server never sends a response back at all. In Fiddler I can see both the request and response in one line when it works. When it doesn't work, I only see the request and no other lines are produced. Does this mean the server never responds? (I was hoping I would see the server's response on a separate line that is ignored by the app on the browser.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't see a response, then when the browser sent the data, the timeout is most likely in trying to connect to the server to send the data.

So, the lack of response is that nothing came back.

So, your server is having an issue with accepting connections at times.